# using rsa infrastructure digitally signed document

Tags: rsa, sha1, pfx, pkcs#12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in billing.crt -inkey billing.key -out client.pfx
```

I have used this command to create a client certificate, I have a normal certificate, private key and a public key which files do i need to give to the verifying server is it `public.key` or `public.pfx`, I'm using linux OS. thanks in advance

Comment: and if it is public.pfx how do I create this kind of public key?

Comment: This is not a question. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **openssl command-line utilities** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: James thats specific. thanks!